# Why a function is executed two times?

Tags: python, call, return, execution

I import a function from a package:

```
from read_video import getData
```

I wrote this function. It has the following structure:

```
def getData()
   print 'start'
   ...
   print 'end'
```

Then I call this function:

```
video_data = getData()
```

On the screen I see;

```
start
end
start
end
```

I thought that may be my function calls itself. But it is not the case. I also thought that my function calls a function that call my function. But it is also not the case. Does anybody knows what can be a reason of this strange behavior?

Comment: is this the full code ? you call getData() and getVideo() is called ???

Comment: You do realize people can only guess? You provided way too little code.

Comment: @rocksportrocker in the original question I made a mistake. It is always `getData`.

Comment: @Mark Byers, it does not print anything if I just import the module.

Comment: Use the python debugger and step through your code....

Comment: Can you provide the full module code?

Comment: Fyi, windows supports forward slashes. So there is no good reason to use backslashes in hardcoded paths. But if you do, use `r'strings'` instead of `'strings'` since you don't have to escape every backslash in those strings (except a trailing one)

Comment: What if you call it like `v_data = getData()`

Comment: please try to find the absolute minimum amount of code that will exhibit this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code to this:

```
import pdb

def getData():
  print 'start'
  pdb.set_trace()
  ...
```

And once you've dropped in an interpreter prompt, press `w` to see a call trace. This should help you figure things out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my own question. My code was saved in the `dimension.py` file. So, I call the program by `python dimension.py`. In the `dimension.py` I had the following line:

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\me\\datamining\\Dimensions\\')
from dimension import *
```

The problem was that the package was also in the file called `dimension.py` (file with the same name but located in another directory). Importing from `dimension.py` caused one additional execution of the program in `dimension.py` (not the package).